BadMethodCallException when using ralphjsmit/laravel-horizon-cron-supervisor package
When I update my project (compose update), I get the next error:
$ composer update
...
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

   BadMethodCallException 

  Method Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Event::tap does not exist.

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Macroable/Traits/Macroable.php:113
    109▕      */
    110▕     public function __call($method, $parameters)
    111▕     {
    112▕         if (! static::hasMacro($method)) {
  ➜ 113▕             throw new BadMethodCallException(sprintf(
    114▕                 'Method %s::%s does not exist.', static::class, $method
    115▕             ));
    116▕         }
    117▕ 

  • Bad Method Call: Did you mean Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Event::at() ? 

      +7 vendor frames 
  8   artisan:35
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()

In laravel.log we found this stacktrace:
[2024-10-23 12:33:45] production.ERROR: Method Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Event::tap does not exist. {"exception":"[object] (BadMethodCallException(code: 0): Method Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\Event::tap does not exist. at .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Macroable/Traits/Macroable.php:113)
[stacktrace]
#0 .../vendor/ralphjsmit/laravel-horizon-cron-supervisor/src/Supervisor/SupervisorServiceProvider.php(26): Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\Event->__call()


If we look at the line of code and later we go to see the Event class, we can't find the tap method.
My compose file:
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.1",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.3",
        "inspector-apm/inspector-laravel": "^4.7",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.54",
        "laravel/horizon": "^5.7",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "predis/predis": "^2.1.1",
        "ralphjsmit/laravel-horizon-cron-supervisor": "^1.0.1",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "dev-develop"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/breeze": "^1.6",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}


In summary, when running composer update, a BadMethodCallException occurs because the method tap does not exist in the Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Event class. This issue arises from the ralphjsmit/laravel-horizon-cron-supervisor package, which calls a method that doesn't exist in the Event class. The tap method is not part of the Laravel framework, as seen in the Event class documentation. The error trace points to a call in the SupervisorServiceProvider.php file
Has this happened to anyone else? Thanks.

Fixed in 1.4.1, thanks for reporting!

After review the commit history of the source code file, I downgrade the library version from 1.4.0 to 1.3.0, and then no errors were reported when update the project.
